# Ruby Complex Event Processing

Tags: ruby, complex-event-processing, event-stream

Is there an open-source complex event processing (CEP) engine for ruby?

I'm looking specifically for something that offers stateful analysis, not just rules-engine-style antecedent-predicate productions.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like rulecore which is language independent. It seems to use webservices and xml.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to make use of the Java based [Esper CEP](http://esper.codehaus.org/) by using JRuby. [This blog post](http://www.igvita.com/2011/05/27/streamsql-event-processing-with-esper/) gives a quick, but clear, run through with a basic example.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been following the CEP scene too closely (I worked with Cayuga from Cornell University, now open source, and Esper around 2006-2007), but I haven't heard of one yet. Most of them appear to be in .NET, Java, and C/C++. There are some event-related libraries for Ruby, but none seem to be anywhere near the capabilities of CEP engines such as Esper or StreamBase.

Answer (score 0):

Most CEP engines are servers that you can talk to in various language independent ways. For example delivering events using TCP/IP, JMS, http or other protocols.